# Dynamic text box in Java

Tags: java, swing, text, dynamic

how do I make a text box which the user can insert text into, then that text can be saved to some variable?

Comment: By 'text box' I presume you mean a JTextArea?  What problems are you experiencing with getting the text into a variable?  What have you tried?

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Comment: I'm Using a JFrame, and inside that I have a JPanel, in which I want to insert a textbox like the one you're typing in when you type in a comment right here. I then want whatever text was inserted into the box to be saved to a string. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of text box? Pick one: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JTextField` is probably the class you are looking for.

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
yourPanel.add(textField);
```

This will add the `textField` into your `JPanel`. Then at any point in your code where you have a handle to your textField, call `getText();` of your `JTextField`.

```
String s = textField.getText();
```

See this tutorial for a better reference:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A `JTextField` or `JTextArea` will do what you are asking for, but you'll need either a button or a listener to actually know when to save this to a String.

javax.swing is Event based, which means that you cannot extract the text like this:

```
JTextField myField = new JTextField();

//wait for user input

String s = myField.getText(); //not guaranteed to work!
```

Instead, you may want to make a "Submit" button that will send the text to your program when it is clicked:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html